# Databricks: Error while adding maven dependency : Cannot download some libraries due to transient Maven issue

Tags: databricks

I am trying to add the maven dependency  in Databricks Analytics platform

Getting error: Unknown error while checking maven dependencies: Cannot download some libraries due to transient Maven issue. Please try again later.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the coordinates which you are trying?

Comment: its there on the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks strange. AsFor a deeper investigation and immediate assistance on this issue, if you have a support plan you may file a support ticket for the same.

Meanwhile, you can create the library manually:

**Step1:** You can download the jar file from [MVN repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intel.analytics.zoo/analytics-zoo-bigdl_0.9.1-spark_2.4.3/0.6.0).

[image]

**Step2:** Create library by selecting "`Library Source`" as "`Upload`" and "`Library Type`" as "`Jar`" and select the jar file downloaded.

Here are the steps to create library manually by following the below steps:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to manage this dependency using the dbx deploy, instead of manually uploading to the cluster?